# Can not install wine using terminal

Tags: apt, wine

I've tried to install wine in ubuntu 12.10 through terminal. I write this script to install wine: `sudo apt-get install wine`
but its is showing this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
void@Void:~$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

please tell me some solution for this problem or tell me some alternative to install wine in my system.

Comment: have you tried the software center?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a  # this will configure packages if needed
sudo apt-get install -f   # fix widespread packages errors
```

You may have to repeat these lines according to terminal's output. When it suggests you command, you should try that suggestion. And after you get rid of problems with packages, you should write this to install Wine:

```
sudo apt-get update       # update packages lists
sudo apt-get install wine # install wine
```